# Fancybox goes behind navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I have the following div structure

```
<div class="page">
     <div id="top" class="header-container">
         <!-- navigation menu and search box in here -->
     </div>
     <div class="main-container col1-layout">
         <!-- Fancybox for photo gallery and onther content in here -->
     </div>
</div>
```

When my page is scrolled all the way to the top (normal loading position of the page) my Fancybox goes behind the navigation menu, but when I scroll down the page this issue is solved.

How can I do to overlay the Fancybox on top of the navigation menu? I'm using jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js

Thanks

Comment: you can use absolute positioning with z-index to overlay

Comment: change fancybox z-index greated than menu z-index or menu smaller than fancybox z-index

Comment: z-index is the only solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other answers suggest z-index is what you need to implement.

But to use z-index you need to apply position:relative; (or position:absolute;) for it to work.

Comment: To the whole main-container div or just for the fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the css property `z-index` in one class of the menu and of the fancybox div:

```
.header-container {
    z-index: 1;
}

.main-container {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Elements which should be on top of others must have a greater `z-index`.

Comment: Rob by doing this nav bar goes behind the content or images when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Increase z-index of fancybox element. This may help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. z-index + position relative solved my problem!